# Why do some Structure Groups display the "published" icon?

Tags: 2011, publishing

Some Structure Groups in Tridion are displaying the "published" Icon

Can any one suggest why it is displaying the published icon for a Structure Group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because *someone* clicked the "Publish Structure Group information" checkbox in the publishing dialog.

Starting with Tridion 2011 you can publish information about the Structure Group itself to the Content Delivery tier. This could be used - for instance - to build navigation dynamically (not that I would ever recommend it).

Comment: I have seen since SDL Tridion 2009 era and in > 10 implementation that navigation has been built using the Numbered Nomenclature of Structure Group - I would like to know your thought why you really not recommend it...is it something many of (if not all) Tridion devs missing?

Comment: I don't recommend building the navigation from the PUBLISHED structure groups.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, just wanted to know the downside of it...can you share your thoughts WHY you really not recommend that?

Comment: Because you'd be querying the broker for data that doesn't really change that often. Use SGs for navigation: yes. Use published SG metadata to generate navigation: no.

Comment: I guess perhaps I'm not being clear. With publishing SG metadata you could generate your navigation entirely on the delivery side. That's what I don't recommend. No problems at all with using SGs for navigation, but I don't recommend doing it on the delivery side.

Comment: ahh..got your point...we used to do the one suggested by you - We use SGs for navigation by using a C# TBB + PT + Page and generating navigation XML on delivery side...and do not use published metadata to generate navigation...Glad to know not much of mess has been made by me in past :P